# Typescript member decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I would like to create custom member decorator, I mean:

```
class Example
{
   @Decorator
   test:any;
}
```

According to typescript specification, arguments to function of such a decorator are:

```
the name of the nember - say key
the prototype of the class for an instance member - say targer
```

Why is there prototype passed to that function? Why not orginal class, but  base class? I would like to refer to orginal class, not to base class. Is there any way I can refer to orginal class, maybe by using constructor property of `target`, which is constructor of orginal class?
Decorator class will be called at runtime, so maybe we can use that fact, and use some clear js?

Please help me, I've spend so much time on that issue!

EDIT:
Let's clearify what effect do I want to achieve.

```
class A {

   attributes:string[];// Array to keep meta data about member

   @Decorator("base")
   test:string;
}

class B extends A {

   @Decorator("varB")
   my_var::string;
}

class C extends A {

   @Decorator("varC")
   my_var::string;
}

export function Attr(name: string) {
  return function (target: any, key: any) {

    if (!target.attributes) {
      target.params = [];
    }
    target.attributes.push(name);

  };
}
```

Both classes `B` and `C` inherits array `attributes`, but I what that array in `B` to be like `{ "base", "varB"}` and in `C` `{ "base", "varC"}`. `base` is from base class decorator. The problem is that real result is `{ "base", "varB", "varC"}`, because `target` in function decorator is always base class for `B` and `C`, and `Object` for class `A`. That's always prototype.

Comment: it would help if you could share with us what's the bevahiour this decorator should have.

Comment: @toskv thanks for attention, I edited post.